# Evaluating $\int e^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right)dx$ and $\int e^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right)dx$ Simultaneously Using Linear Algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, indefinite-integrals

While experimenting with some linear algebra and some integrals, I believe I may have found one way of evaluating the general antiderivatives of $e^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right)$ and $e^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right)$. Hopefully, this is not a duplicate as I have used Approach0 to try to find similar methods but could not find any. I apologize in advance if this is a lot to read, so I'll try my best to be as concise as possible.

**(Proposal)** Evaluate $\displaystyle\int e^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right)dx$ and $\displaystyle\int e^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right)dx$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b$ are both not $0$.

**(Attempt)** Consider

$$\operatorname{span}\left\{e^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right), e^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right)\right\} := \operatorname{span}\left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$$

and the differentiation operator

$$D(f) := f'.$$

To prove the span of the two vectors is invariant under $D$, observe that

$$D(v_1) = \frac{d}{dx}e^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right) = ae^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right)+be^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right)$$

and

$$D(v_2) = \frac{d}{dx}e^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right) = be^{ax}\cosh\left(bx\right)+ae^{ax}\sinh\left(bx\right).$$

Thus, applying $D$ to the two basis vectors still yields a linear combination of those basis vectors, so we can find a matrix for $D$ by gathering the coefficients. Let

$$A := \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$D\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

To antidifferentiate, we find the inverse of $D$, call it $D^{-1}$, so $D^{-1} = A^{-1}.$ Suppose $\overrightarrow{C} = \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R^2}.$ Then

$$\displaystyle \int \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}dx = A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} + \overrightarrow{C} = \dfrac{1}{\operatorname{det}(A)}\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b \\
-b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} + \overrightarrow{C}.$$

Simplifying gives us

$$\displaystyle \int \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}dx = \frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\begin{bmatrix}
av_1-bv_2+c_1 \\
-bv_1+av_2+c_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Multiplying $\dfrac{1}{a^2-b^2}$ into the vector provides us the general antiderivative of $v_1$ on the top and the general antiderivative of $v_2$ on the bottom.

**(Question)** Is this correct? If so, how can we apply this method to other integrals out there?

Any answer/comment shedding some light is appreciated.

**(Thoughts)** It seems like this method only works if we can solve $D(\overrightarrow{v}) = A(\overrightarrow{v})$, where $D, A$ are the same as in my solution and $\overrightarrow{v}$ is an element of the span of two elements. This leads me to believe I was somewhat lucky in getting the right antiderivatives. For context, my background in algebra consists of an undergraduate, upper-division linear algebra course, and an abstract algebra course. If I missed anything trivial, please let me know.

Comment: I haven’t checked your exact working but I’ve seen this before, this is definitely a real thing. If you can find a finite dimensional function space which is closed under differentiation, you can differentiate/antidifferentiate with matrices

Comment: This is also fun because if you do it "right" you pick up a 1-dimensional kernel, which accounts for the $+C$.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_ordinary_differential_equations) [topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).

Comment: I would rather consider the linear span of $e^{(a+b)x}$ and $e^{(a-b)x}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That is a better idea. I didn't think of that. Thank you.